# How to create a temporary cursor in meteor

Tags: meteor

Im working on a mobile app that needs to display a suggested set of data and will not update as the user removes suggestions and will show as empty if the user removes all (5) entries in the set. If been trying with reactive:false which seems to work but starts after second item removed. Anyone have a way to achieve this?

Comment: I don't think I fully understand the question, but would a local collection (i.e. a `new Meteor.Collection()` without a name) work?

Comment: It might, but I'm not sure how to publish from the collection to a local only collection... Say collection users publishes to local collection matches, only 5. How would I do that?